# Are there differences between Functionality and Functional Requirements

Tags: terminology, documentation, requirements

I'm writing some documentation in a project in a tool. In this tool of mine, and write in specific area, I have here use Case, Business Rule, N-Diagram Types, and Functionality and Functional Requirements.

So I got me wondering, Are there differences between Functionality and Functional Requirements?

In my vision, a Functionality a implementation of a Functional Requirement, is it correct? What other differences one can find between them?

Comment: As far as I know, Functionality and Functional Requirement are synonyms in this context.

Comment: Here's clarification based on my deduction on my way to work this morning; I believe things need to BE functional. ... things need to HAVE funtionality
. Let me know if you disagree.

Answer (score 4):

Functionality is what a program does.

Functional requirements are what you *want* the program to do.